# Update a column of a table with the count of other column in the same table in a MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

recordid    customerid      product id     count 
  1              2             12             3 
   2             4             10             1
   3             2             3             3
   4             3             12             2
   5             3             10             2
   6             2             7             3
   7             5             3             1
   8              .... 
   9              ....

I want an update query that will count the no of occurrence of each customer id and update the count column which will initially be empty.
the end result should be like above
The column names are dummy, my actual table is different.
It has data in millions of rows.The query should be speedy
I tried the query but it gets stuck...
update tablename, (select count(recordid) as count,customerid from tablename group by customerid) as temp set count=temp.count where customerid=temp.customerid

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JOIN` in `UPDATE`.

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableName A
JOIN 
(SELECT customerid,Count(customerid) as cnt
FROM TableName
GROUP BY customerid) as B ON A.customerid= B.customerid
SET A.count = B.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t see right:

```
update tablename, (select count(recordid) as count,customerid from tablename group by customerid) as temp set count=temp.count where customerid=temp.customerid
```

Why is there a comma after `update tablename` like this:

```
update tablename,
```

I am also reformatting for readability:

```
UPDATE tablename (
  SELECT count(recordid) AS count, customerid
  FROM tablename GROUP BY customerid
) as temp
SET count=temp.count
WHERE customerid = temp.customerid
```